# Processing complex JSON with Spring 3 MVC

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

I'm trying to process the JSON below with Spring 3 MVC :

```
var fields = {
    "fields" : [ {
        "groupId" : "mission",
        "type" : "text",
        "id" : "company_name",
        "label" : "Nom de l'entreprise",
        "size" : 0
    }, {
        "groupId" : "mission",
        "type" : "text",
        "id" : "theme",
        "label" : "Thème",
        "size" : 0
    }, {
        "groupId" : "mission",
        "type" : "textarea",
        "id" : "descriptive",
        "label" : "Description",
        "size" : 0
    } ]
};
```

Here is how I send it :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/GestaWeb/internshipConfiguration/proposal",
  data: fields
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

The params passed via http (it's a copy of the Chrome web dev console) :

```
fields[0][groupId]:mission
fields[0][type]:text
fields[0][id]:company_name
fields[0][label]:Nom de l'entreprise
fields[0][size]:0
fields[1][groupId]:mission
fields[1][type]:text
fields[1][id]:theme
fields[1][label]:ThÃ¨me
fields[1][size]:0
fields[2][groupId]:mission
fields[2][type]:textarea
fields[2][id]:descriptive
fields[2][label]:Description
fields[2][size]:0
```

And my Spring 3 MVC controller :

```
package controller.internshipConfiguration;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/internshipConfiguration")
public class ProposalModelConfigurationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/proposal", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView form(ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("internship config view");
        return new ModelAndView("internship/formModel");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/proposal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String form(@RequestParam(value="fields") String fields) {

        System.out.println("Fields rofl: " + fields);

        return "ok";
    }

}
```

When I execute the Ajax I've got a 400.
It works fine if I pass a simple object like this : {fields: "foo"}

Answer (score 0):

set contentType to json in yr ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/GestaWeb/internshipConfiguration/proposal",
  data: fields,
  contentType: "application/json"
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

You should also create a java class that matches the fields - jackson/spring will propulate the class automagically. So yr controller would like something like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/proposal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String form(@RequestBody MyPojoForFields myPojoForFields){}
```

MyPojoForfields is normally a domain object or DTO.

I haven't tried it myself but I would also guess that supplying a List as the method's parameter would also be fine.

More reading [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/).

Comment: I tried it with the List as the parameter type and now I get a 415.